# Use RequireJS config file as the build file?

Tags: requirejs, minify, web-deployment

I've got some paths configured in require-config.js as follows:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/javascript',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min'
        // etc. -- several paths to vendor files here
    },
}
```

I am trying to get the optimization working for deployment. The [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) say I should have a build.js that looks something like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: 'javascript',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min'
    },
    name: 'main',
    out: 'main-build.js'
})
```

**Is there a way to have the optimizer read my config file** instead of (or in addition to) build.js? I don't want to have to manually keep the paths configured the same in both files if they change.

I tried to just run  `node r.js -o path/to/require-config.js`, but it threw an error, "malformed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

*Edit*: for clarification, my require-config.js file is the config only, not my main module. I did this so I could use the same configuration but load a different main module when unit testing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the way your config options are defined. Taken [from the RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html):

> In version 1.0.5+ of the optimizer, the mainConfigFile option can be used to specify the location of the runtime config. If specified with the path to your main JS file, **the first requirejs({}), requirejs.config({}), require({}), or require.config({}) found in that file will be parsed out** and used as part of the configuration options passed to the optimizer:

So basically you can point your `r.js` build file to your config options that will also be shared with the browser.

You will need to make use of [the mainConfigFile option](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L35)

Comment: So I guess in my html, the two script tags (require-config.js, require.js with data-main) will become three (require.js with NO data-main, require-config.js, and main.js). And then I'll restructure the config file to invoke `require.config()` rather than just set `var config`. Is that right?

Comment: In your scenario of wishing to keep the config on its own, I'd say yeah, that would be the way.

Comment: Hmm. Despite what the documentation says, it still requires my config file be in JSON format:
"Error: The config in mainConfigFile /opt/shootq/nimbus/public/javascript/require-config.js cannot be used because it cannot be evaluated correctly while running in the optimizer. Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer."

Comment: Are you using any variables in your config? - https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/270#issuecomment-8070939

Comment: That was it. I had a urlArgs setting for cache busting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For other's reference:

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

The build settings (no need to repeat your config.js lib inclusions here):

```
baseUrl: 'app',
name: 'assets/js/lib/almond', // or require

// Read config and then also build it into the app
mainConfigFile: 'app/config.js',
include: ['config'],

// Needed for almond (and does no harm for require)
wrap: true,
```